# drupal_render($form) not rendering a form

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I wonder if anyone has found a solution to the problem I'm seeing.  I've built a very simple "beginner's form" in drupal.

```
function simple_nameform() {
    $form = array(
        '#method'           => 'post',
        '#prefix'           => '<div class="staf">',
        '#suffix'           => '</div>',
        'your_name'         => array(
            '#title'        => t('Your Name'),
            '#type'         => 'textfield',
            '#description'  => t('Please enter your name')
        ),
        'submit'            => array(
            '#type'         => 'submit',
            '#value'        => t('submit')
        )
    );
    return $form;
}
```

I've put this form in a module, with info, I've enabled the block in admin.  When I'm on the main page render I run the commands

```
<div class="simple_overlay" id="simple">
    <h1>Send to a Friend</h1>
    <?php
        $output = drupal_get_form('simple_nameform');
        drupal_render($output);
    ?>
</div>
<pre> 
<?php // debug purposes only
          print_r($output); 
    ?>
</pre>
```

The form does not appear to render from the "drupal_render" line, however, the $output variable is most definitely full of something that looks very much like it might be a drupal form.

(it's a huge array filled with my form elements.  at parts it even manages to render some of the elements to page correctly).

Anyone with an idea of what I've missed?

Comment: The question could easily be answered by reading the documentation of the used function: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_render/7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php print render(drupal_get_form('simple_nameform')); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT -- My original answer was incorrect in that it applies to Drupal 6.

it seems that the form builder function in D7 needs 2 arguments, `$form` and `$form_state`

```
<?php
function simple_nameform($form, &$form_state) {
/...
?>
```

I wonder if the _valdiate and _submit function aren't also required, as they are present in the D7 example here:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/form_api/7

if that doesn't work, try using [hook_forms()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_forms/6) to register your form with a module

---

**original solution for D6**

```
<?php 
$output = drupal_get_form('simple_nameform');
print $output;
?>
```

`drupal_get_form` returns a rendered form.  notice the last line here: [drupal_get_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/6)

also, unrelated, you probably need to add a line to your submit button:

```
<?php

        'submit'            => array(
            '#type'         => 'submit',
            '#value'        => t('submit'),
            '#executes_submit_callback' => true
        )
?>
```

and to make debugging easier, try this:

```
<?php // debug purposes only
          drupal_set_message("<pre>".print_r($output,true)."</pre>"); 
?>
```

(the 2nd arg of print_r makes it return inline instead of pooping at the top of your document.)

Comment: See I'd tried that (with echo instead of print) and got the result "Array" printed in the space that I expected the form to be rendered in.  One of the non-standard drupal features installed is "chaos tools" is there perhaps something that is creating a conflict ?

Comment: is this drupal 6.x or 7.x?

Comment: nevermind -- just saw in your tags.. it's 7

Comment: that form generation link might turn out to be far more useful than what I was doing.  the command render() as opposed to drupal_render appeared to have the desired effect.

Comment: thanks so much for your help though.  I've learned a good deal from your answer.